# Convert from sql query condition to REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am converting an SQL query condition like:

```
where req_number like '169___[3,4,5,6]10%' OR req_number like '169___[3,4,5,6]51%'
```

I tried to execute query in Oracle using condition belove but no result return:

```
where (REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '169___[3456]10$') OR REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '169___[3456]51$'))
```

Result look like for example `169011310` so _ are numeric characters

Comment: Remove `$` in both `REGEXP_LIKE`, it means *end of string*.

Comment: Also tried without `$` at the end but query does not return any result and sql query works perfectly.

Comment: Because `_` means any single char. Replace with `.` in regex. `169` must be at the start, so add `^` at the start - use `where (REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '^169.{3}[3456]10') OR REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '^169.{3}[3456]51'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` in regex means *end of string*, you need to remove it because `%` in TSQL means *any text*, any zero or more chars, and `REGEXP_LIKE` does not require a full string match.

As `_` in TSQL means *any single char* you can replace each `_` with `.` in regex.

The `169` must be matched at the start of string because TSQL `like` patterns must always match the entire record, so you need to add `^` at the beginning of the regex.

You can use

```sql
where (REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '^169.{3}[3456]10') OR REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '^169.{3}[3456]51'))
```

You can write `.{3}` as `...`, however, it is easier to scale such a regex later, using the limiting quantifier `{n}` (*`n` times*).

Also, you may change `[3456]` into `[3-6]` since the digits are consecutive here.

And optimizing it further, since the expresions only differ in the last number, you may just use alternation:

```sql
where REGEXP_LIKE (req_number, '^169.{3}[3-6](10|51)')
```

where `(10|51)` matches either `10` or `51`.